# gulp.watch going into endless loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch

Here's my gulpfile.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var clean = require('gulp-clean');
var mincss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var angularFilesort = require('gulp-angular-filesort');

var env = 'development';

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start('static', 'html');
});

gulp.task('production', ['set-production', 'default']);

gulp.task('development', ['default'], function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/less/**/*.less', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./*.html', ['html']);
});

gulp.task('static', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./src/static/*.*'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/static'));
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('./dist', {
        read: false
      })
      .pipe(clean());
});

gulp.task('html', ['styles', 'vendor-js', 'templateCache', 'scripts'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./*.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/js/**/*.js'])
            .pipe(angularFilesort()), {
                'ignorePath': 'dist/js',
                'addRootSlash': false,
                'addPrefix': 'scripts'
            }))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/vendors/**/*.js', '!./dist/vendors/less/less.js'], {
            read: false
        }), {
            'name': 'vendors',
            'ignorePath': 'dist/vendors',
            'addRootSlash': false,
            'addPrefix': 'vendors'
        }))
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['./dist/css/*.css'], {
            read: false
        }), {
            'ignorePath': 'dist/css',
            'addRootSlash': false,
            'addPrefix': 'styles'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/less/*.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', mincss()))
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', concat('styles.css')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', concat('scripts.js')))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('vendor-js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['./vendors/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.js', 'vendors/angular/angular.js'])
        .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/vendors'));
});

gulp.task('templateCache', function() {
    return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.tpl.html')
        .pipe(templateCache('templatesCache.js', {
            module: 'templatesCache',
            standalone: true,
            root: './templates/'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('set-production', function() {
    env = 'production';
});
```

When I run "gulp development", it goes into an infinite loop like this.
[image]

[image]

I am sure there is an issue with the way I am trying to watch stuff.
Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your screen doesn't show any loop

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your problem comes from your `html` watcher.

The fact you're watching for changes on all your `.html` files to launch the `html` task, that is injecting references to your scripts and your styles files into the `index.html` will cause this infinite loop.

Just when the files are finished to be injected and written to the disk, the final `dest` of your `html` task, this trigger your watcher that restart everything again and again.

So remove the watcher or exclude the `index.html` from the watcher to prevent the restarts

```
gulp.watch(['./*.html', '!index.html'], ['html']);
```

Comment: That did it. You sir, are a genius. :)
I didn't realize gulp-inject makes changes to the file as it runs.

However, can you suggest a way I can watch for changes in html and rebuild it?

Any other suggestions regarding my gulpfile are very welcome.

Comment: The fact to watch for html changes to trigger this task seems strange to me, because your index.html is not supposed to change. I would advice you to listen for new created files to trigger this task. You can have a look to [gulp-watch](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch) that will allow you to get new files, and btw I'm far from genius :)